# Problema con programa de C++, no reconoce bien los tipos de datos

Tags: c++, números-enteros

tengo que hacer un programa que determine la población de un determinado país después de un determinado número de años, los años que han de pasar para que a ese ritmo se llegue como mínimo al doble de la población inicial, y la población tras esos años. Para ello, tengo que pasar los siguientes valores a la función:

- Población Inicial
- Tasa de natalidad
- Tasa de mortandad
- Tasa de inmigración
- Número de años

Primeramente declaro todas las variables que me van a hacer falta:

```
int pob_inicial, tasa_natalidad, tasa_mortandad, tasa_inmigracion, pob_final, anios;
long long pob_doble=0, pob_trans=0;
const int MAX=50;
bool esMayor = true;
int p[MAX], c[MAX];
```

A continuación, leo los valores necesarios, con sus determinados filtros:

```
do{
    cout << "Introduzca la poblacion inicial: ";
    cin >> pob_inicial;
}while(pob_inicial <=0);

pob_doble = pob_inicial*2;

do{
    cout << "Introduzca la tasa de natalidad: ";
    cin >> tasa_natalidad;
}while(tasa_natalidad <= 0 && tasa_natalidad >= 1000);

do{
    cout << "Introduzca la tasa de mortandad: ";
    cin >> tasa_mortandad;
}while(tasa_mortandad <= 0 && tasa_mortandad >= 1000);

do{
    cout << "Introduzca la tasa de inmigracion: ";
    cin >> tasa_inmigracion;
}while(tasa_inmigracion <= 0 && tasa_inmigracion >= 1000);

do{
    cout << "Introduzca el numero de años: ";
    cin >> anios;
}while(anios < 0);
```

Ahora, calculo la población transcurrida tras los años introducidos anteriormente (este bucle lo hace bien):

```
p[0] = pob_inicial;

// Calcular la población transcurridos los años
for(int i=1; i<=anios; i++){
    p[i] = p[i-1] + ((p[i-1]/1000)*tasa_natalidad) - ((p[i-1]/1000)*tasa_mortandad) + ((p[i-1]/1000)*tasa_inmigracion);
}
pob_final = p[anios];
```

Ahora, planteo el bucle para calcular el doble de la población inicial:

```
c[0] = pob_inicial;
int contador = 1;
// Calcular el doble de la población inicial
while(c[contador] >= pob_doble){
    c[contador] = c[contador-1] + ((c[contador-1]/1000)*tasa_natalidad) - ((c[contador-1]/1000)*tasa_mortandad) + ((c[contador-1]/1000)*tasa_inmigracion);
    contador++;
}
```

Por último, conforme a contador, hago un bucle para para población tras esos años obtenidos:

```
p[0] = pob_inicial;
// Calcular la población transcurrida
for(int i=1; i<=contador; i++){
    p[i] = p[i-1] + ((p[i-1]/1000)*tasa_natalidad) - ((p[i-1]/1000)*tasa_mortandad) + ((p[i-1]/1000)*tasa_inmigracion);
}
pob_trans = p[contador];
```

El problema es que por algún motivo, la variable pob_doble me la saca como negativa. Hago un cout de esa variable, y me saca un valor negativo. He intentado cambiar los bucles, cambiar los tipos de las variables y demás. Un valor deseado sería introducir los siguientes datos: 1375570814 32 12 7 3 (respectivamente) y obtener 1490027497 (población transcurrida tras los años), 27 (número de años hasta alcanzar la población doble) y 2824131580 (la población tras esos años).

Llevo unos días atrancados. No sé qué más tocar y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada tipo de dato puede almacenar un rango de valores determinados.

En el caso de `int`, que típicamente ocupa 32 bits (16 en algunas arquitecturas), nos deja 31 bits para almacenar los números (1 bit se usa para el signo). Esto nos da un total de:

```
2^31 = 2.147.483.648
```

Es decir, el número más grande que puedes almacenar en un `int` es **inferior** al número que pretendes almacenar (`2.824.131.580`).

Tienes dos posibles soluciones:

1. Si no se van a usar números negativos, puedes usar `unsigned int`. Dado que este tipo no necesita signo, doblarás el rango de valores `4.294.967.296`.
2. En vez de apurar tanto, cambia el tipo de dato. Los estándares modernos de C++ proporcionan un tipo de 64 bits, `long long`, y su correspondiente sin signo, `unsigned long long`. Con estos tipos no deberías tener problemas para almacenar los números que estás utilizando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta. La cosa es que tengo establecidas las dos variables que pueden tener valores más grandes (pob_doble y pob_trans) como long long, y pob_doble me la sigue sacando como negativo. De igual forma si cambio el tipo a unsigned long long.

Comment: @d3vcho cambia todas las variables. Si tu tienes `long long = int + int`, la suma se va a calcular con `int` y después se hace la conversión a `long long`, por lo que sigues arrastrando la misma restricción

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias @eferion! Todo muy claro :)